# Batch decline MacOS Calendar events with Applescript

Tags: macos, calendar, applescript

When I am out of the office, I want to decline all the iCals during the impacted period, and I was looking to automate it with Applescript.  Although I have gotten to the point of finding my attendee record in the event, I can't seem to find a way to set my response to "declined". I'm trying to avoid having to individually click through each invite and would rather just select them and run a script.  Thanks to [this](https://codingbulljunky.wordpress.com/2017/06/23/selected-event-in-calendar-%E2%86%92-things-to-do/), I was able to get this far.

```
use scripting additions

set defaultsReply to (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.ical SelectedEvents")
set selectedEvents to parseDefaults(defaultsReply)

if selectedEvents = {} then
    display notification "Please try again" with title "No Calendar Event Selected"
    return
end if

set eventReferenceList to {}
repeat with sEvent in selectedEvents
    set {eventID, calendarID} to sqlQuery(sEvent)
    tell application "Calendar"
        set eventReference to event id eventID of calendar id calendarID
        
        
        set theName to summary of eventReference
        set theDate to start date of eventReference
        set theAttendees to attendees of eventReference
        
        repeat with anAttendee in theAttendees
            if display name of anAttendee is "David Johnson" then
                set myRef to anAttendee
                set myStatus to participation status of myRef
#               set participation status of myRef to "declined"
            end if
        end repeat
        
        #       tell application "Things3"
        #           set newToDo to make new to do with properties {name:theName, due date:theDate}
        #       end tell
        
        
    end tell
    return
end repeat


on parseDefaults(resultText)
    set localUIDs to {}
    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, quote}
    set resultItems to text items of resultText
    set text item delimiters to TID
    repeat with i from 1 to (count resultItems)
        if i mod 2 = 0 then set end of localUIDs to resultItems's item i
    end repeat
    return localUIDs
end parseDefaults

on sqlQuery(localUID)
    local dateString, localUID
    if localUID contains "/" then
        set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "/"}
        set {dateString, localUID} to text items of localUID
        set text item delimiters to TID
    end if
    
    set sqlText to "
        SELECT DISTINCT zcalendaritem.zshareduid AS eventID
             , znode.zuid as calID
          FROM zcalendaritem
          JOIN znode
            ON znode.z_pk = zcalendaritem.zcalendar
           AND zcalendaritem.zlocaluid = '" & localUID & "'
        ;"
    
    set sqlPath to POSIX path of (path to library folder from user domain) & "Calendars/Calendar Cache"
    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "|"}
    set {eID, cID} to text items of (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of sqlText & " | sqlite3 " & quoted form of sqlPath)
    set text item delimiters to TID
    return {eID, cID}
end sqlQuery
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `.sdef` file of iCal? It is located at `/System/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/Resources/iCal.sdef`.

Comment: I hadn't, do you mean looking at attacking this problem through a Cocoa interface?

Comment: No, the iCal.sdef file contains documentation for how to do anything that is possible with an application. The documentation follows this [formatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) (search for conventions).

Comment: **participation status** property is read/only. But, it is possible to set it other way. **By recreating the event**. You duplicate to new event everything except of attendees, then add attendees, then delete old event. When you add attendee to new event, its participation status is settable. Calendar.app see this way created event like old event, with 1 change: participation status of attendee "David Johnson", for example. Example of duplicating the event: https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=205642 Example of adding attendees: https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=27152

Comment: If the even it not my event, can I still recreate someone else's invite and then decline for me without either disconnecting from their event, or potentially messing up other attendee's status/linking?